# Syntax Highlighting with mod_dav_svn

Tags: apache, svn, mod-dav-svn, geshi

I am looking for a simple way to present code in the browser via Apache's mod_dav_svn Subversion module that is syntax highlighted (my instance is Ruby, but it shouldn't matter since mode of these modules support all the major languages).  Does anyone know a quick way to do this?  In a world of Geshi, noone wants to look at black text code.  Apache 2.2 with Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution, but it's not "easy".

I tried to redirect file rendering through PHP for some time, but authentication, and read access rights, is an issue. My current solution involves using SVNIndexXSLT for loading [JSHS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/).